# Heroku Postgres not able to connect ERROR: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "...", user "...", database "...", SSL off

Tags: heroku, knex.js, heroku-postgres

My production setup in my knexfile.js looks like this:

```
production: {
client: 'pg',
connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
migrations: {
  directory: './data/migrations'
},
seeds: {
  directory: './data/seeds'
},
```

I have tried adding `ssl: true` and `false` and also added `ssl: {rejectUnauthorized: false }` to no avail. This has never been an issue for me before so not sure why this error keeps happening. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same exact issue and finally found my way to:

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#pg810

Ultimately, all I had to do was to add the suggested Environment variable on the Heroku dashboard.  (`PGSSLMODE=no-verify`)

[Heroku Config Vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKzH6.png)

It's also worth mentioning that I made sure to have the most recent versions of both PG and Knex in my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "knex": "^0.95.1",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
},
```

Comment: I set this env var and have the latest deps, running `NODE_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL) npx knex migrate:latest` and I still get the error, any ideas?